# how to use memoryStorage() to upload files in node.js

Tags: node.js, multer

I am learning how to upload files in node.js, I was able to upload files to a local folder in my system when I used multer.diskStorage

```
const storag = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'uploads');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const { originalname } = file;
        cb(null, originalname);
    }
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storag });
router.post("/lecture", upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    return res.json({ status: 'OK' });
});
```

but as soon as I changed the multer.diskStorage to multer.memoryStorage as I will like to post directly to google cloud storage, the server returns this same route with a 404 error, i will like to know what the problem is

```
const storag = multer.memoryStorage()
const upload = multer({ storage: storag });
router.post("/lecture", upload.single('file'), instructorController.createLecture, (req, res) => {
    return res.json({ status: 'OK' });
});
```